# Probably simple: showing and hiding a div using removeClass/addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This should be really simple and maybe I'm missing something obvious but here's my problem.

I have the div below with the bootstrap class "hidden".  When the submit button on the form is clicked the form is submitted, if an error is returned from the callback function I remove the "hidden" class so that the user sees an alert message

Remove the "hidden" class to show the alert message:

```
$('.not-submitted').removeClass('hidden');
```

The html that contains the "hidden" class:

```
<div class="not-submitted alert alert-error hidden">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
    <strong>Error!</strong> Form not submitted, please try again.
</div>
```

The above works fine but when the user tries again and it fails for the second time the alert message doesn't show because the user has closed the alert message box and the "hidden" class has already been removed, and in fact when removing the class it seems to be removing the entire div and not just the "hidden" class.

So what I need to do is add the class back in.  I thought it would be easy enough just to do:

```
$('.not-submitted').addClass('hidden');
```

Unfortunately this didn't work (and it wouldn't do if it's removing the entire div).

Anyone got any ideas on how best to sort this?

Comment: `$(//whatever).click(() => $('.not-submitted').toggleClass('hidden'));` maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `data-dismiss` will disintegrate your poor *Alert*.
Remove the *Dismissible* data `data-dismiss` from your **×** button.

```
<a class="close">×</a>
```

Add this jQ:

```
$('.not-submitted .close').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.not-submitted').addClass('hidden');
});
```

Comment: That worked perfectly on the console, I'm using Meteor so I had to Meteorify your JQ - all working now, thank you :)

Comment: @user1532669 oh nice, glad you did it! Y'w. Happy coding.